# ios- Error while exporting archieved file in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, ipa

I am facing One problem while exporting archieve file. My Client given me access as member to my developer account. now from my account I selected
their team with their bundle id in xcode. After making archieve while exporting I am getting this issue

Please suggest me what I can do. Do I need to ask for admin access?

[image]

Comment: You should have admin or agent right for creating certificates...ask you client to give you aceess as admin or agent. The error you got is  self explainary.. :)

Comment: look this : https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was I made 1 ipa file using my account and after that I asked them to resign my app. So they dont have to provide admin access to others and at the end they can have an app using their credentials.